# Powershell: How to enclose an array of strings with quotes so that SQL "IN" operator works?

Tags: powershell

I'm basically asking users to enter some formIds separated by a comma and passing that string to a function which does a SQL query update. The problem is I'm not able to use the IN operator since the query has to be in the format: "(''),('')".

I want to make this query work:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Details] SET Field1 = 0 WHERE FormId in ('123','456','789')
```

And for this I want to accept this user input:

> 123,456,789

How can I get this to work?

```
Function Execute-Query([String[]] $FormIds)
{
$arr = $FormIds -split ','

ForEach ($formId in $arr)
{
    echo $formId
}
$dataSource = "x"
$user = "x"
$pwd = ""x
$database = "x"
$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;"

$sqlcmd = new-object "System.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand"
$sqlcmd.connection = $con
$sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 600000
$sqlcmd.CommandText = “UPDATE [dbo].[Details] SET Field1 = 0 WHERE FormId in (????)”
$rowsAffected = $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$connection.Close()

}
$strFormIds = Read-Host "Enter FormIds:"
Execute-Query $strFormIds
```

Comment: If you're passing user-provided strings straight through, note that this opens you up to some substantial security vulnerabilities. Best practices for handling user-provided data in SQL calls for using bound parameters and keeping data out-of-band from code; when your tools don't support bound parameters, that calls for using different tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how `IN` comes into play, but assuming you just want to construct a query string as in your example, use the following subexpression instead of `????` in your code:

```
$("'" + ($FormIds -join "','") + "'")
```

That said, your `Read-Host` call will not automatically convert your `'123','456','789'` user input into an array of *individual* strings - instead, it will create a *single*-element array whose only element is that very string *as a whole*.

You must therefore explicitly parse your single-string user input into an *array* first, as follows:

```
[string[]] $formIds = $strFormIds -split '[, ]' -ne ''
```

Note the set of characters to split by - `,` and `<space>` - so that both `123,456` and `123, 456` or even `123 456` would work. The `-ne ''` part filters out empty elements that result from multiple adjacent spaces, for instance.

Comment: `"'" + $($arr -join "','") + "'"`

Comment: @JosefZ: The `$` around the `(...)` makes no difference in this case.

Comment: This totally worked! The IN operator is also working as expected. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the id's to your method with double quotes like shown below, can't you just use the $FormIds variable directly (assuming you have validated it and removed potential sql injection before of course)?

```
Function Execute-Query([String[]] $FormIds)
{
    $query = "UPDATE [dbo].[Details] SET Field1 = 0 WHERE FormId in ($FormIds)"
    $sqlcmd.CommandText = $query
    Write-Host $query
}

Execute-Query "'123','456','789'"
```

This should output:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Details] SET Field1 = 0 WHERE FormId in ('123','456','789')
```

Comment: What if the user input is: 123,456,789? I will edit the qs to avoid any confusion.